# parsing date in a .NET command line tool using RegEx

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

In a vb.net command line tool I am working on there is a command called period P:
I want to specify dates in the following formats

```
P:2009                       'translate this to 01.01.2009 to 31.12.2009
P:2008 To 2010               'translate this to 01.01.2008 to 31.12.2010
P:01.01.2012 To 22.11.2013   'stays the same
```

After I get the text that comes after P: I want to validate it using regex and add the missing parts to it since I will use it in an sql command.

Any adivce?

Comment: Are you sure it's `31.01.2010` in the second line and not `31.12.2010`?

Comment: @PeterStahl sorry, fixed it ;)

Comment: Any code to show? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: If the format in your data is consistent, formats 1,2 are trivial to detect, parse, and convert to form 3 - why do you want to use a regex when you could write 2-3 lines of simple code (e.g. you could use text.Contains(".") and then text.Contains("To") to differentiate the 3 cases, and then it's just a matter of inserting a few characters as appropriate)

Comment: Why not use date parsing classes? .NET sure has some, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is C# code, can be directly converted to vb.net :)

```
     string input = "P:2008 To 2010";
     string result = Regex.Replace(input, "^P:([0-9]{4})$", "P:01.01.$1");
     if (input == result)
     {
        result = Regex.Replace(input, "^P:([0-9]{4}) To ([0-9]{4})$", "P:01.01.$1 to 01.01.$2");
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for regex here; just String.Split() around "To", and then String.Split around "." on the results. Depending on the size of the resulting arrays, you know whether to create the resulting text from only the year or the three components.

Comment: +1 for not using a regex. Who said, "If you try and solve a problem with a regex, you now have two problems"?

Answer (score 1):

I know, you are not looking for a Python solution, but maybe this here gives you an idea of how you could do it in your language:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: re.sub(r'P:(\d{4})', '01.01.\g<1> to 31.12.\g<1>', 'P:2009')
Out[2]: '01.01.2009 to 31.12.2009'

In [3]: re.sub(r'P:(\d{4}) To (\d{4})', '01.01.\g<1> to 31.12.\g<2>', 'P:2008 To 2010')
Out[3]: '01.01.2008 to 31.12.2010'
```

A solution without regular expressions could look like this:

```
In [4]: def create_date(s):
  ....:     if s.startswith('P:'):
  ....:         years = s[2:].split(' To ')
  ....:         if len(years) == 1:
  ....:             return '01.01.' + years[0] + ' to 31.12.' + years[0]
  ....:         elif len(years) == 2:
  ....:             return '01.01.' + years[0] + ' to 31.12.' + years[1]         

In [5]: create_date('P:2008')
Out[5]: '01.01.2008 to 31.12.2008'

In [6]: create_date('P:2008 To 2010')
Out[6]: '01.01.2008 to 31.12.2010'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not going to pass a string for a date to SQL (ARE YOU?), you might as well parse the date(s) to ensure validity:

```
Imports System.Globalization

Module Module1

    ' Take a string of year or year and month or year and month and day and
    ' convert it to a DateTime, defaulting to month=1 or day=1 if they are missing
    ' Throw an exception if this is not possible.
    Function MakeExplicitDate(s As String) As DateTime
        Dim cul = New CultureInfo("en-GB")
        Dim dt As DateTime

        If Not DateTime.TryParse(s, cul, Nothing, dt) Then
            s &= "-01"
            If Not DateTime.TryParse(s, cul, Nothing, dt) Then
                s &= "-01"
                If Not DateTime.TryParse(s, cul, Nothing, dt) Then
                    Throw New Exception("Could not parse date.")
                End If
            End If
        End If

        Return dt

    End Function

    Sub Main()

        Dim s = "P:2009 to 2011.02.13"

        If s.StartsWith("P:") Then

            s = s.Substring(2, Math.Max(0, s.Length - 2))
            Dim dates = s.ToLowerInvariant.Split({"to"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

            If dates.Count > 2 Then
                Throw New Exception("Too many dates supplied.")
            End If

            Dim datesToUse As New List(Of DateTime)

            For i = 0 To dates.Count - 1
                datesToUse.Add(MakeExplicitDate(dates(i)))
            Next

            For Each dtu In datesToUse
                Console.WriteLine(dtu.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            Next

        End If

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```